# Supervised Learning with Form Recognizer

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to analyze a form using Microsoft's Form Recognizer API but I am not seeing the results I had hoped for. After training the model on my form, the keys it has generated are very rarely what I want to be. Does anyone know if there is a method to improve accuracy of key recognition? I was thinking there might be some way to give a list of key/value pairs when training as a form of supervised learning.

[Here](https://ibb.co/10ckkxC) is a sample of the form I'm trying to parse.

I'd expect keys of 'Year', 'Make', 'Model', and 'VIN'. But instead the model is returning a key of 'Vehicle' with values 'Year', 'Make', 'Model', and 'VIN' and their subsequent values.

I know I specifically asked about supervised learning but really any techniques or tips on how to improve the accuracy of a form recognizer model would be appreciated.

Comment: please add an inline example instead of a simple image representing one data line, it'll be simplier to read and help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Azure Form Recognizer now offers a Supervised Learning Tool to tune models for forms which are difficult to train with the default unsupervised learning mode.

Here's how you can get to the tool:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool

Answer (score 0):

Did you train a model with 5 sample forms ? Can you try adding an empty form without the values to the training data and see if it helps ? Are the forms good quality scanned or are they tilted ?

Following are some tips on how you can improve the accuracy:

**How to Build a training data set for a custom model**
When you use the Form Recognizer custom model, you provide your own training data so the model can train to your industry-specific forms. You can train a model with five filled-in forms or an empty form (include the word "empty" in the file name) plus two filled-in forms. Even if you have enough filled-in forms to train with, adding an empty form to your training data set can improve the accuracy of the model.

It's important to use a data set that's optimized for training. Use the following tips to ensure you get the best results from the Train Model operation:

•   If possible, use text-based PDF documents instead of image-based documents. Scanned PDFs are handled as images.
•   Use one empty form and two filled-in forms if you have them available.
•   For filled-in forms, use examples that have all of their fields filled in.
•   Use forms with different values in each field.
•   If your form images are of lower quality, use a larger data set (10-15 images, for example).

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried all of those tips. I trained the model with an empty sheet and 10 filled out forms with all different data.

Comment: Are the forms high quality scans or are they tilted and location of keys and values differ on the form ?

Comment: They are all high quality scans. I actually had much better success trying to train the model with 30 forms instead of 5. Perhaps I just wasn't using enough testing data.